# Matplotlib: How to make a contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that I want to do a contour plot: `mixed_model_pdf([[x,y]])`.

It takes points of `[x,y]`, instead of X,Y seperately as input. That is, `mixed_model_pdf([[-5,-5]])`, or `mixed_model_pdf([[-5,-5],[-5,-4]])`

But to do `plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)`, The `Z` value should be placed in specific order, how can I do that?

Now, I can get away with this:

```
X = Y = np.arange(-30, 31, 1)
N, M = len(X), len(Y)
Z = np.zeros((N, M))
for i, (x,y) in enumerate(product(X,Y)):
    Z[np.unravel_index(i, (N,M))] = mixed_model_pdf([[x,y]])
Z = Z.T    
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# Plot 2d prob density
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=80)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 10, alpha=.75, cmap='jet')
```

But this looks really ugly, it `transpose` the `Z`, and still need  `X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)`.

What would be a better way to do it?

UPDATE:

Now, I can make the code a lot more clear:

```
X = Y = np.arange(-30, 31, 1)
XX,YY=np.meshgrid(x,y)
coords=np.array((XX.ravel(), YY.ravel())).T  
Z = mixed_model_pdf(coords).reshape(61,61)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=80)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 10, alpha=.75, cmap='jet')
```

But how can I shorten the `.reshape()`? It's calculated from `Y = np.arange(-30, 31, 1)`, and I think it may be automated?

Comment: Should work without the line `X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)`.

Comment: @MikeMüller, yes, I tried that, and it works.  But that makes using `contour` even more confusing for me.

Comment: From the docs:  *X* and *Y* must both be 2-D with the same shape as *Z*, or they
must both be 1-D such that ``len(X)`` is the number of columns in
*Z* and ``len(Y)`` is the number of rows in *Z*.

Comment: @MikeMüller, Thanks alot. I did search but didn't find the docs.(Bing does not show it), after playing it for a while, the code looks much better now. But I think it can still be improved, could you see my UPDATE to give any advice?

Comment: You have the docs already `help(plt.contour)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collecting my comments in an answer.

You can call `plt.contourf` in different ways. The docs make this clear:

> X and Y must both be 2-D with the same shape as Z, or they must both be 1-D such that len(X) is the number of columns in Z and len(Y) is the number of rows in Z.

You can get the docs from the interactive Python prompt:

```
>>> help(plt.contourf)
```

or, if you use IPython (Notebook), as you should ;):

```
In [1]: plt.contourf?
```

You can use:

```
Z = mixed_model_pdf(coords).reshape(Y.size, Y.size)
```

to avoid hard coding the `61`.